# Caml Query: How to add additional parameters?

Tags: caml

I have a working query, I want to add additional parameters on the query, such as:

```
<Or>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="Service_x0020_Line" /><Value Type="Choice">RPCS</Value></Eq>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="Service_x0020_Line" /><Value Type="Choice">PLM</Value></Eq>
</Or>
```

How would I be able to add it here?:

```
<And>
<Or>
<Or>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value></Eq>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Not yet submitted</Value></Eq>
</Or>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>For Approval</Value</Eq>
    </Or>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Approval_x0020_Month' /><Value Type='Text'>"+approvalmonth+"</Value></Eq>
    </And>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<And>
  <And>
    <Or>
      <Or>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value></Eq>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Not yet submitted</Value></Eq>
      </Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='BM_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>For Approval</Value</Eq>
    </Or>
    <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="Service_x0020_Line" /><Value Type="Choice">RPCS</Value></Eq>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="Service_x0020_Line" /><Value Type="Choice">PLM</Value></Eq>
    </Or>
  </And>
  <Eq><FieldRef Name='Approval_x0020_Month' /><Value Type='Text'>"+approvalmonth+"</Value></Eq>
</And>
```